# PHP - How to inherit parents constructor and include self destructor

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

in example I want to create a class with constructors, but it should also inherit parent's constructors. I will show you an example.

```
<?php
class Parent{
    public $var1;
    public $var2;
    public function __construct($var1, $var2){
        $this->var1 = $var1;
        $this->var2 = $var2;
    };
};
class Child1 extends Parent{
    public $var3;
    public $var4;
    public function __construct($var3, $var4){
        $this->var3 = $var3;
        $this->var4 = $var4;
    };
};
class Child2 extends Parent{
    public $var5;
    public $var6;
    public function __construct($var5, $var6){
        $this->var5 = $var5;
        $this->var6 = $var6;
    }
}
$instance = new Child1(var1, var2, var3, var4);
?>
```

I want to define a new instance of Child1 and Child2 using Parent constructor attributes and their own attributes. Is there a way to do that? Sorry if this seems too easy, I just started learning PHP and concept of OOP. Thanks a lot!

Comment: PHP doesn't call parent/ancestor constructors for you. You have to explicitly do `parent::__construct()` in each of your child constructors.

Answer (score 5):

From your sample code you can do:

```
class Child1 extends Parent{
    public $var3;
    public $var4;
    public function __construct($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4){
        parent::__construct($var1, $var2);
        $this->var3 = $var3;
        $this->var4 = $var4;
    };
};
```

You can always call the method of a parent class, using the syntax `parent::method` when you are in the same method as parent class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for!